# Multiplication on relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-database, translation, multiplication, relational-algebra

Would you please help me to find direct translation of the following SQL query into the relational algebraic expression?

```
select s.name, c.course_id, t.grade
from student s, course c, takes t
where s.ID = t.ID and c.course_id = t.course_id
and t.year = 2010
```

I have one idea which is:

```
π s.name, c.course_id, t.grade (σ s.id= t.id ^ c.course_id=t.course_id ^ t.year=2010 (course c x (takes t x student s)))
```

But, I am not sure about multiplication of the tables in relational algebra?

Edit: I am not sure about correct Cartesian join of the given tables in the written relational algebra?

Comment: “A × B” in relational algebra is not multiplication, it is a cartesian join; it joins every row in A with every row in B. If you want to join only specific columns, you need to use a theta join. If you know every column in every table must join all identically-named columns, you can use a natural join A ⋈ B.

Comment: It was asked in exam and not allowed to use joints for this question.

Answer (score 1):

Use natural join

(Student natural join takes ) will equate the id of both the tables.

(Student natural join takes) natural join course  will finally equate the course_id  and than using select operator select the year as 2010. Now using projection select the name course_id and grade.

One thing to remember is that natural join will automatically equate the attributes which are common ( in this case id and course_id ) and also the common attributes will be selected only once unlike the cross product